# Angular 6 compile template runtime

Tags: angular, d3.js

Im working with Angular 6 and D3 library(helps you with DOM manipulation) and i add some html tags in runtime with angular material attributtes(matTooltip).

If i have some structure created  at first, the tooltip works perfect but if i add the same structure in realtime it does not work.

I guess that is due to the process of compilation with angular and i was wondering if there is a way to solve this.

I have created a basic example where you can see what i explained. In app.component.html there is a g tag with tooltip that works fine.
In app.component.ts i added the same tag in runtime and does not.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7ctyq

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the first case is made **before compilation**, and the second one is made **after compilation**.

To phrase it in a more understandable way :

when you write

```
<g id="tick1" matTooltip="200">
```

At compilation, Angular reads this tag, and understands that it has to display a tooltip via a directive.

So it will replace this `matTooltip` attribute, with something like `data-mat-tooltip="200"`, and use it in the stylesheet to display the tooltip, something like

```
g[data-mat-tooltip]:after {
  content: attr(data-mat-tooltip);
  // Styles & animations
}
```

On the other hand, when you create code in your component's logic, you code is compiled, and it adds the attribute **after the compilation**.

matTooltip not being an HTML attribute, nothing happens.

If you want to solve this issue, you can take a look at [how the directive works](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/tooltip) (brace yourslef ofr a hard time), or you can try to use the first solution you used, which in my opinion, is the easiest one.

Comment: I understood the problem thanks for the explanation but i dont know what you mean with the solution that i could take.Can you explain?

Comment: Put the attribute in your template, where it belongs, and not in your component's logic.

Comment: The problem is that i need to create it in runtime in the real application due to some logics needed in the component

Comment: Then you will need to create your own tooltip for that, because you can't use the material tooltip after the compilation.